# checkinstall gets "stuck" upon listing files installed in home directory

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, checkinstall

I have used `sudo checkinstall` to install a package (after the usual `./configure`). After successful installation it asks me

```
Some of the files created by the installation are inside the home directory: /home

You probably don't want them to be included in the package.
Do you want me to list them?  [n]:
```

If I now return `y` I get a long list of file names that I can scroll through until I eventually arrive at `(END)`. At this point I don't know what to do. No combinations of keys that I could find prompted `checkinstall` to proceed to the next step. Utlimately I used `ctrl + z` to exit and reran the process. I then answered `n` to above question and it proceeded happily to ask me

`Should I exclude them from the package? (Saying yes is a good idea)  [n]:`

as I would expect it to do. What is going wrong here, am I missing a command to get it to proceed after showing me the list? Or is this a bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was confused when I ran into this as well.  Press q to exit this list and finish the process.